# PHP utf8_decode works great except when saving in MySQL database

Tags: php

I'm reading data from a Access database with PHP & ODBC driver to insert into MySQL. It works nicely, except with data containing accents.

I use the following to retrieve the data from a Access Table:

```
$conn = new \PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ={$dbPath}; Uid={$dbUser}; Pwd={$dbPass};");
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
$stmt->execute();
```

When looping through results I have a field named `name` which holds the user name.

```
$name = $row['name'];
```

The output of this value into the screen shows:

Jo�o

The correct word is "João". When saving in the MySQL database it saves **Jo?o**.

If I output the value into the screen using the `utf8_decode` works great, it shows **João**.

```
print_r(utf8_decode($name));
```

But when saving using the same function it saves once again **Jo?o**.

I have also tried to save the data using `htmlspecialchars(utf8_decode($name), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` but the value is saved as empty.

How do I insert into MySQL database the correct value "João"? My MySQL table has the collation `utf8_bin`.

Comment: have you read [UTF-8 All The Way Through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

By using the `mb_convert_encoding` along side with `utf8_encode` the value is saved correctly in the database.

```
mb_convert_encoding(utf8_encode($name), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')
```